# How to set up a large set of first order non-linear differential equations in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, nonlinear-functions

I am relatively new to writing my own code for Matlab though I have used the program a decent amount. Right now I am attempting to code a series of first order non-linear differential equations. They are all in one of two forms like the equations here:

[image]

Eventually I will need a set of 30 differential equations.

What I was hoping to do was create a function that could make the differential equation for each component of a certain form, combine them into a single system (essentially a matrix with 1 column and a row for each component), and then solve using a Matlab solver like ODE45, the dsolve function, or something like that to solve the system.

I have not yet found a way to make a function set up this large of a system that works with either dsolve or ODE45. The results always either gave me an empty sym or an error that the initial conditions were not compatible with the system or some other error. So what I am wondering is if there is another way to go about setting up a system that is this large and has nonlinear differential equations.

I do *not* want someone else's code; I just want an idea for how to go about setting this up in Matlab because nothing I have tried has worked so far.

Comment: In the first equation, how does the index `j` in the expression relate to the equation index `i`? In the second equation the index `i` is bound to the sum, so that this question relative to the equation index `j` does not occur.

Comment: I have corrected the first equation to include a summation with respect to index j. Essentially, the term following the summation is accounting for growth or depletion of the component due to its interactions with other components of the system. Index j are resources. Index i are consumers of those resources.